# Paypal credit card processing without leaving my site?

Tags: paypal

Is there a way to have paypal process my credit cards in the background without having the user to leave my site or have a paypal account?

Or is this feature only for "Pro" accounts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available for normal Account also.

**The Direct Payment User Experience**

Direct Payment enables buyers to pay by credit or debit card during your checkout flow. You have complete control over the experience; however, you must consider `PCI compliance`.

When buyers choose to pay with a credit or debit card, they enter their card number and other information on your website. After they confirm their order and click Pay, you complete the order in the background by invoking the DoDirectPayment API operation. Buyers never leave your site. Although PayPal processes the order, buyers aren't aware of PayPal's involvement; `PayPal will not even appear on the buyer's credit card statement for the transaction.`

The following diagram shows a typical Direct Payment flow:

Direct Payment Flow
[image]

[Direct Payment Paypall without leaving Site](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPDirectPayment/)

Comment: Thanks! So I do not need to pay extra for a "pro" account to do this?

Comment: @Clay Smith you are Welcome yes you are right.you do not need to pay extra.